# Serialize an avro object to string in python

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, avro

In Python 3.7, I want to encode an Avro object to String.
I found examples converting to byte array but not to string. 
Code to convert to byte array:

```
def serialize(mapper, schema):
    bytes_writer = io.BytesIO()
    encoder = avro.io.BinaryEncoder(bytes_writer)
    writer1 = avro.io.DatumWriter(schema)
    writer1.write(mapper, encoder)
    return bytes_writer.getvalue()
```

`mapper` is a dictionary which will populate the avro object.

`io` provides with `StringIO` which I assume will need to be used instead of `BytesIO` but then what encoder to use with that? How do we serialize this?

Answer (score 0):

if, for example, `a` is your Avro object, you can use `a.to_json()` method of Avro and then `json.dumps(a)`